# Cloudera Hive create table hang

Tags: hive, cloudera

I'm newbie to hive, and recently I installed Cloudera express quickstart VM. I'm able to start hive instance, but when I execute hive cli from command line to create a table, the command hangs there all the time. Any idea on what's wrong?

Comment: This issue has been resolved after manually startup zookeeper.  No need to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below from Cloudera community blog

*After restarting Hive Service, I tried creating table using Hue worked.. After that create tables in hive started working.. Not sure about the magic behind..*

I followed exactly same. Stopped Hue followed by Hive and started Hive & Hue. One extra thing which I did is to follow the quick start steps in Hue which installed couple of sample tables/databases in Hive. Hope this helps for others who are new to Cloudera VM and facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run the ZooKeeper if turned off!

Error:@ hadoop-cmf-hive-HIVEMAETASTORE__.LOG.OUT
 
Error @ hadoop-cmf-hive-HIVESERVER2-quickstart.cloudera.log.out
Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

I persume, there is connectivity issue for the matastore, so did start Zookeeper  that resolved my sisue.
And-> Table create failed after Zookper turned to Off, which is clear  evidence that, to write something to HDFS (via Hive) zookeeper needs in turned on state.